# How to structure cancelled orders?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, nosql, application-design

I'm working with NoSQL Database "Firebase", and I have a node that contains 6 categories "services" in everyone I put an array of orders well?

now when the user logged I get/fetch all orders bassed on his category lets to say "plumber",
So he can accept an order or reject it if he accepted it this order remove from this category "Plumber" and will not appear to other users it will move on to node else and that's fine,

now if he wants to reject this order, that's mean this order shouldn't appear again to you? but will appear to other users!

so how can I handle it to if he rejects an order he can't see it

[image: DB]

Comment: At first: you should use consistent language. _Cancel_ may mean: the original request was removed. _Reject_ means the provider doesnt want to serve the order. I think you shouldn't move the rejected orders, only flag them with the provider id. Like what if you have more providers for the same category? One of them rejects the order by someone else may takes it.

Comment: @n3ko sorry about that :) which part you can't understand it well?

Comment: @n3ko sounds good, the flag should be in another node? or the same?

Comment: Wow, you are fast :) So if you want to evolve in the field, i suggest to read about ddd (aka domain driven development). The questions like that... all depends on your decisions. I would put a rejected field in every order as an array, which contains the userid list of _who doesnt wants this job_. I doesnt know mutch about permissions in firebase, if its a problem to uncover a userid list like this between users, you probably should create a node under the user where you collects the rejected orders. The later version can be less performant if you have a lot of orders.

Comment: maybe i will go with the first option :D "rejected field in every order as an array" Thank you for help & your suggestion too